# Element-wise vector-matrix exponentiation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector, exponent

I would like to exponentiate the vector `x = {x1,x2}` element-wise with the non-square matrix `A = {{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}` so that the result is `x^A = {x1, x1x2, x2}`. Is there an operation for element-wise vector-matrix exponentiation in Mathematica?

To clarify, the operation should be the following:

```
{{x1^1 * x2^0},
 {x1^1 * x2^1},
 {x1^0 * x2^1}}

= {x1,
   x1 x2,
   x2}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Times @@@ Map[x^# &, A]
```

> {x1, x1 x2, x2}

Comment: great, thanks a lot @eldo!

Comment: You're most welcome

Comment: @eldo Please explane about symbol `@@@` I don't understand.

Comment: It's the short form of [MapApply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html)

Comment: I notice that you did not accept an answer to this question. Is there 
something that remains to be addressed?

Answer (score 5):

```
Inner[ReverseApplied[Power], A, x, Times]

(* {x1, x1 x2, x2} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it directly:

```
Times @@ (x^Transpose@A)
(* {x1, x1 x2, x2} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {x1, x2};
A = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
Pick[x, #, 1] & /@ A // Map[Apply[Times]]
```

---

> {x1, x1 x2, x2}

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {x1, x2};
A = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
```

---

Using `Table`:

```
Table[Times @@ (x^#[[i]]), {i, Length@#}] &@A
```

> `{x1, x1 x2, x2}`